File change and close tracking on Mac in Swift
Is there any reasonable way to track file edits and closures in Swift on a Mac?
What I need:

(Completed) Open a file from the server (With default application - for example: MS Word for docx)
Track changes to the file, mainly OnChange, OnClose, and based on those, send commands and the file back to the server

What i tried:

I read forums.swift article and coresponding with this article also developer.apple.com and stackoverflow.com post. Everybody talks about the fact that it basically can't be done. At least not properly.
I tried to get some scripts from the AI, but that was also completely useless.

I currently want to try catching OnChange by displaying the resized file, and OnClose by using a file that creates a word and deletes it when closed. It's not an ideal solution, it's not even tested yet, but if we're primarily concerned with Word, Excel and PowerPoint, I don't currently have a better solution.
Update 1
The file count based detection method works and is tested on xlsx, docx, pptx, which are my main target. Even so, I don't find this solution very elegant and at the same time I have a problem to watch OnChange (I haven't found a way to check it yet)
class FileWatcher {
    private let directoryPath: String
    private var lastFileCount: Int = 0
    private var timer: Timer?

    init(filePath: String) {
        self.directoryPath = (filePath as NSString).deletingLastPathComponent
        self.lastFileCount = countFilesInDirectory()
        startWatching()
    }

    private func startWatching() {
        print("Starting timer")
        timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(checkDirectory), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .common)
    }

    @objc private func checkDirectory() {
        let currentFileCount = self.countFilesInDirectory()
        if currentFileCount < self.lastFileCount {
            print("FILE CLOSED")
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
            //TODO: Logic which will respond to closing file
        }
        self.lastFileCount = currentFileCount
    }
    
    private func countFilesInDirectory() -> Int {
        do {
            let fileURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: directoryPath)
            return fileURLs.count
        } catch {
            print("Error counting files: \(error)")
            return 0
        }
    }

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}

Update 2
I did some refactoring and mainly add onchange (depending on modificationDate)
class FileWatcher {
    private let directoryPath: String
    private var lastFileCount: Int = 0
    private let filePath: String
    private var lastModificationDate: Date?
    private var timer: Timer?
    
    init(filePath: String) {
        self.filePath = filePath
        self.directoryPath = (filePath as NSString).deletingLastPathComponent
        self.lastFileCount = countFilesInDirectory()
        startWatching()
    }
    
    private func startWatching() {
        print("Starting timer")
        timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(checkDirectory), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .common)
    }
    
    @objc private func checkDirectory() {
        // Check for file modification changes
        if(isFileModified()) {
            print("OnChange")
        }
        
        if(isFileClosed()) {
            print("OnClose")
        }
    }
    
    func isFileClosed() -> Bool {
        let currentFileCount = self.countFilesInDirectory()
        if currentFileCount < self.lastFileCount {
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
            //TODO: Logic which will respond to closing file
            self.lastFileCount = currentFileCount
            return true
        }
        self.lastFileCount = currentFileCount
        return false
    }

    
    func isFileModified() -> Bool {
        guard let currentModificationDate = getFileModificationDate(filePath: self.filePath),
              currentModificationDate != self.lastModificationDate else { return false }
        self.lastModificationDate = currentModificationDate
        return true
    }
    
    private func getFileModificationDate(filePath: String) -> Date? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        do {
            let attributes = try fileManager.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath)
            if let modificationDate = attributes[.modificationDate] as? Date {
                return modificationDate
            } else {
                print("Modification date not found for file at path: \(filePath)")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error retrieving attributes for file at path: \(filePath) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    private func countFilesInDirectory() -> Int {
        do {
            let fileURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: directoryPath)
            return fileURLs.count
        } catch {
            print("Error counting files: \(error)")
            return 0
        }
    }

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}

Why i cant use contentAccessDate? Its date the resource was last accessed. I need to indicate and react to closing the window and finishing editing (OnClose), so this is not the application for me.

Have you looked into AX Accessibility?

@soundflix No, I honestly don't even know what to make of it in my context.

Sorry I misread that you were also interested in document open/close.

Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately it's not the same problem. I've updated my post, I need to watch the final OnClose event.

Unless Word has purpose-built APIs to help with this, you might not have any better alternative than to listen to the file system for changes, parse the .docx files, and try to determine the changes for yourself.
